# Send Nested JSON with file in HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I want to send this object to the server:

```
public class Product
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }        
        public ICollection<Photo> photos { get; set; }

    }
```

This object have a collection of other objects:

```
public class Photo
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I send the `Product` object with its collection of `Photo` objects? and How can I send a file in the `Photo` object?(I want to use `application/json` not `form-data`)

Comment: What have you tried? what does not work?

Comment: I think instead of sending IFormFile you can send file content as string

Comment: what is the expected payload server side? are you writing both server and clien? or just client?

Comment: @viveknuna
Is it work for an image?

Comment: @zaitsman I use form-data, but because I have nested JSON to send, it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @zaitsman I'm writing both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should send the file contents as a Base64 string

Create the string like this

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path\\to\\file.jpg");
String 64string = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then just update your photo class to have a string for the file, as assign it

```
public class Photo
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public String fileContents { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

Photo p = new Photo() { url = "...", fileContents = 64String, ..... }
```

Of course this assumes that your server expect this and can decode accordingly!  I assume you also are writing the server side code.

You can convert it back like this:

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(64string );
File.WriteAllBytes("path\\to\\file.jpg", bytes);
```

Comment: Is it accepted as an IFormFile in the server? or must change the server-side?

Comment: you need to change it back to bytes

Comment: @VilsadPP Is this way work for other clients? because I have multiple clients, one of them wrote in java and another wrote in javascript.

Comment: It's a string. All clients can accept it, and Base64 encoding/decoding is a very common task. I'd bet both Java and JavaScript can handle them.

Comment: all languages can  encode and decode  base64 strings, so it won't be a problem